# Q&A: Complex deadlock assessment test and how answers are rated

Tags: java, multithreading

The following code has been constructed for a test. In this test the reader is asked to explain why the code will enter a deadlock less then a second after starting the code.

Can anyone please **exactly** describe what causes the deadlock in this code?

```
public class Test {

  static class FailerThread implements Runnable {

    final Object[] objects;
    final Random random;
    final int number;

    public FailerThread(final Object[] objects, final int number) {
      this.objects = objects;
      this.random = new Random();
      this.number = number;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
      final boolean isWriter = number % 2 == 0;
      int index = random.nextInt(objects.length);
      try {
        while (Thread.interrupted() == false) {
          synchronized (objects) {
            if (isWriter) {
              while (objects[index] == null) {
                System.out.println(number + ": Index " + index + " is null, waiting...");
                objects.wait();
              }
              for (int copyIndex = 0; copyIndex < objects.length; ++copyIndex) {
                if (objects[copyIndex] == null) {
                  objects[copyIndex] = this.objects[index];
                }
              }
              objects.notifyAll();
            } else {
              objects[index] = null;
            }
          }

          ++index;
          if (index >= objects.length) {
            index = 0;
          }
        }
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      }
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    final Object[] objects = new Object[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < objects.length; ++i) {
      objects[i] = new Object();
    }

    final int NUM_THREADS = 32;
    final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(NUM_THREADS);
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; ++i) {
      executor.execute(new FailerThread(objects, i));
    }
  }
}
```

**Edit:** The official answer to this test (similar to what Tudor wrote, just more detailed)

The above construct deadlocks, because at some point all "writers" wait on a null, but since those writers are the only one who could release them, they will hang indefinitely. The more important question however is: why?

At a first glance the code looks like those writers are dominant. Each loop a single thread (either writer or nuller) is selected to process on the array, but while a nuller only writes a single null, a writer eliminates all nulls in the array. So one would expect that deadlocking - while possible - is very unlikely (yet surprisingly the code deadlocks within a second). On a closer look however this assumption turns out to be false, because we are dealing with threads.

Given enough execution time, in a multi-threaded application what matters is: which part of the code is actually able to block? Let's take a look at the possible worst-case scenarios for writers/nullers:

- A nuller can - in worst-case - execute without any effect. That is: it writes null to a position in the array that is already null.
- A writer can - in worst-case - block indefinitely.

Furthermore at the beginning of the synchronized block a (more or less) random candidate is chosen to enter. At the beginning this is 50% for both writers and nullers, however for each blocked writer, the chances favor into the direction of the nullers. Even though a successful write eliminates all nulls, the chance for nullers is always 50% or more, because the chance for writers (thanks to blocking) constantly diminishes. So from a threaded perspective the nullers are actually the dominant part, as the entire system is designed to favor them as candidates for the synchronized block.

In addition - and this is the important part - **the order of execution with threads is undefined**. A naive impression is that which thread is allowed to execute alternates, but this is not the case. A synchronized block has no preferences, and which thread gains access is undefined (one could say: completely random, although no random is involved). So with all 16 threads waiting on the synchronized, the chance that within 20 executions threads alternate perfectly, is exactly equal to the chance that 20 writers or 20 nullers are called in a row. But since nullers are dominant (20 writers just do nothing), calling 20 nullers in a row is almost guaranteed to set the entire array to null, which then causes any subsequent writers to block indefinitely.

If you add more logging output to the code to see which thread is actually selected, you will very soon see something like 10 or more nullers being called in a row, usually within the first 200 loops. Right after that the system hangs.

**Why this question was asked**

I am currently developing a test set for assessments for expert Java programmers and with all code written it eventually needs to be tested. The good news: it succeeded. ;)

Now before you complain about improper use of StackOverflow: please see this one as Q&A. And there is much to learn from this example for real implementation of multi-threaded architecture. As this is an expert level question - as expected - not many people were able to answer it nor even understand it. The good thing however about expert level questions is, that you can as well learn much from expert level answers. That is why I included the fully detailed answer.

**How the candidate is rated**

Foreseeing that some people will consider this question to be way too difficult for an assessment test, and to give your the viewpoint of the tester, this is how candidates will be rated:

Yes the question is too difficult, and no one is expected to find the correct answer during the test, what matters is how they approach the problem. Every day a programmer encounters tasks that he/she has never solved before and does not know how to solve right away, therefore having a good skill in problem-solving is what matters in this business. No one can know everything, but everyone can learn.

In general there are 4 possible results:

1. The candidate does not know the answer and says so. This is a good beginner level, because the candidate has the strength to admit that during a stressful test situation. A good student is the one that listens, and therefore can be taught.
2. The candidate does now know the answer, but either blames the "bad" question (aka down-vote) or comes up with a wrong answer, that he/she then defends furiously. This is basically the worst-case candidate: he is at beginner/intermediate level, but considers himself an expert and therefore refuses to learn and will be stuck at this level. In a team this candidate will either block advancement of the team (if they believe him to be the "expert") or become a nuisance soon.
3. The candidate comes up with a (more or less correct) answer, and uses a methodical approach to find it. This is a good intermediate/expert level candidate. He/She has developed a methodical approach to challenging tasks and depending on the answer can be expected to advance even further.
4. The candidate uses a methodical approach and comes up with a correct answer. This is the best possible result, but encountered probably only as one in a million.

Comment: Questions must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include your thoughts so far and specific questions on what you don't understand.

Comment: The question is obvious, the code is perfectly describing the problem and my thoughts so far could be wrong as much as they could be correct. This is not a coding issue, but a logic issue.

Comment: Could it be that the notifyAll call is inside the if(isWriter) condition? If only indices corresponding to null writers are used (which I think could happen) notifyAll will never be called.

Comment: Yes, that is the cause, but why does it happen? There are as many writers as nullers, but the writers eliminate all nulls each turn, so there can be at worst time only 1 null?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know if this is the answer you are expecting, but I can see the deadlock happening when these two conditions are met:

1. At least 10 "readers" (non-writers) are able to enter the
   synchronization block in succession without allowing any writer to
   proceed.
2. Each array index from 0 to 9 is picked up randomly at least once by one of the readers that get through the lock.

Since you have 16 readers and 16 writers and the above apply, 10 readers picking up 0 through 9 on the random number generator can null the entire array, thus causing all the writers to be blocked since their corresponding index is null by the time they can get to the `while` loop.

**Edit**: In fact, it is even simpler than that: it's not even required for 10 readers to enter the lock in succession. If K readers enter the lock, and null i positions in the array, with `0 < i <= K` (since indexes can overlap), then if the writers that come in after them all have indexes in the set used by the previous readers, they will be blocked. Since the readers will eventually null out the whole array, if the situation described repeats, it can lead to all the writers blocking in a finite amount of iterations.

Comment: Why would 10 "readers" enter the synchronization block in a succession?

Comment: @TwoThe: The JVM and/or OS scheduler is, if not nondeterministic, at least unpredictable. Any interleaving of instructions among concurrently executing threads is possible, including what I described.

Comment: @TwoThe: See my edit for an even faster way you can reach a deadlock.

Answer (score -1):

It is not a *[deadlock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock)*, since there's only one synchonization resource for all threads.

Simply speaking *[deadlock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock)* is when two threads require two resources for some actions, one thread grabs first resource, second thread grabs second resource and neither could proceed.

In your case it is just all threads either fall into infinite sleep or infinite loop.

All threads in your code are divided in two groups, i'll call them "writers" (those with isWrite==true) and "nullifiers" (technically they do writing too, but they always write null).

At some point *"nullififer"* thread iterates over the array and sets all elements to null. It could be done by a single "nullifier" thread, since there's nothing that stops it from proceeding to next element of an array after setting one to null, as well as by several over the course of several iterations.

No *"writer"* could proceed since they do objects.wait() when their current element is null. So they fall to infinite sleep.

All *"nullifier"* threads infinitely overwrite array with nulls, over and over.

Even if at first *"writer"* threads get more processor time, eventually they will be overrun by *"nullifiers"* since *"writers"* have stop condition, and *"nullifiers"* don't.

**UPDATE:** By the way you don't have to perform boolean comparison inside "if" statement.
You can just write

```
 while (!Thread.interrupted())
```

Which is more readable and concise, and is a common practice.

**UPDATE 2:** You might try to fix by adding objects.wait() in the "nullifier's" else statement, similiar to the one in "writer's" if clause, like this:

```
} else {        
    objects[index] = null;
    while (objects[index]==null) {
        System.out.println(number + ": Index " + index + " is still null, waiting...");
        objects.wait();
    }
}
```

I don't know what this code is supposed to accomplish (it looks just like some random exercise), so I am not sure if solution is correct semantically, but it ought to fix the "rampaging nullifiers" problem.

**UPDATE 3:** If you add logging of thread type in the beggining of the loop you can see that soon enough only threads running are those with isWriter==false
**EDIT:** it's better to do logging after synchronization

```
while (Thread.interrupted() == false) {
    synchronized (objects) {
        System.out.println("running isWriter=" + isWriter + " thread #" + number);
```

Comment: Why would they be "overrun" by nullifiers? Each null run only sets one element to null, then releases the lock on the array.

Comment: After "else" branch it goes to the increment of "index" and then goes to the beginning of the loop. It does release lock, however it doesn't mean it will stop executing right after "else" or index increment. Most likely it will continue to the next iteration and reacquire synchronization.

Comment: I added possible solution to my answer

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but as this is a constructed test question, I am not supposed to fix it, but to explain why it is happening in the first place. And in contrast to your explanation, it is very well possible that after doing the index++, it goes back and has to wait, because a writer is just in progress of fixing all the "holes". That it immediately re-aquires the lock is not likely, and in the case of a multi-core system even more like impossible.

Comment: Writer could not be in progress because of the synchronization block. No matter how many cores machine have and how many threads you spawn only one could be active inside synchronization block, and you synchronize all threads on one object ("objects" array). So the ONLY circumstance that leads to suspending nullifier is when jvm forces current thread to sleep during the increment window, and that window is very short (one increment, one comparison and sometimes one assignment - considering compiler optimizations and multiple ALU i believe it could be performed in on clock cycle).

Comment: Since you don't seem do believe me you can just run the original code and then the fixed one i proposed and see for yourself. Or just add logging of thread's number and type in the begging of the loop to see which threads are running and which are not.

Comment: Added way to check to the answer

Comment: It has nothing to do with not believing you, in fact I do know that this code hangs and where - it is kind of obvious - but the big question is "Why does it hang?". And your explanation is just plain wrong. If there are 2 nullifiers and 2 writers and one nullifier has just finished the loop, then (on multi-core) the next thread __immediately__ gains access, and this one cannot be the previous nullifier, because it isn't even waiting on the lock at this time. So the chance is 2 to 1 that a writer enters, and if it does, all nulls are removed, so we are back to step 1.

Answer (score -1):

The "official answer" that questioneer posted is wrong in so many ways, I'm going to post another answer for those who will stumble on this question in future.

And before someone starts to argue that I'm the "worst case" candidate, who "defends the wrong answer furiously" (as poster implied):

- I did logging and breakpoint debugging (apparantly unlike original
  poster, or maybe he just didn't devote enough time for this).
- I'm not a candidate at all, I'm just trying to use Stackoverflow as intended, providing the best answer I can,if not for benefit of questioneer then others who will be visiting
- And I do this because from original poster's answer others will get
  incorrect notion of what synchronization is.
- And it wasn't me who downvoted question, though ironically original
  poster downvoted my answer

Not to mention that answering "expert"-level question with incorrect assumptions about basics will not give you right answer.

### Synchronization

In the answer poster mentions several times that nuller writes only a single value:

> but while a nuller only writes a single null, a writer eliminates all
>   nulls in the array.
>
> A nuller can - in worst-case - execute without any effect. That is:
>   it writes null to a position in the array that is already null.

There's nothing in the code that makes it true.

Just leaving synchronization clause don't make thread give up execution for another thread.

The sole purpose of synchronization is to guarantee that no two threads will enter same critical section simultaneously, basically it is just a mutex.

[Intrinsic Locks and Synchronization](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html)

[Mutual exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_exclusion)

There are several ways in java to make thread cease control:

- [Thread.yield()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#yield%28%29) - **hints** jvm that it could give execution to
  another thread. Basically it says to jvm *"I did plenty of work here,
  you may give other guys some processor time if you want to, but I
  could also go on."*
- [Thread.sleep()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep%28long%29) - suspends thread for fixed amount of time.
- [Object.wait()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait%28%29) - suspends thread until someone calls notify(which wakes only one waiter)/notifyAll(wakes all waiters) on the same object.
- there are others but they are similiar and usually based on these

**But none of them are used for nullers!
So there's absolutely no guarantee that nuller will write only one value.**

In fact due to the low computational intensity of one iteration it is more likely that during the execution window that thread recieves it will be able to do several iterations.

But again you don't have to believe me, just do logging and debugging. Without actual testing it is all just a demagogy.
(UPDATE: note, that logging should be inside synchronization block)

[image: Screenshot with output of the program, showing how nuller resets several values in a row then one writer overwrites all values and then nuller resets all elements, leading to the problem described in question]
Notice that first nuller resets several values in a row without being interrupted by writer (contrary to what poster says), then writer overwrites array, and then nuller resets all array (several elements at time), while writers fall to sleep, leading to described problem.

**UPDATE:** Furthermore author says

> In addition - and this is the important part - the order of execution with threads is undefined. A naive impression is that which thread is allowed to execute alternates, but this is not the case.

However falls himself a victim of that "naive impression" by expecting that after executing nuller that very thread could not be the one entering synchronization.

### Probabilty-driven development

> Even though a successful write eliminates all nulls, the chance for
>   nullers is always 50% or more

That just throws whole probability theory out of the window, not to mention that writing code based on probabilties is really bad idea, especially when it involves multithreading and long execution time ([infinite monkey theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_monkey_theorem)).

Though in one thing author is right: with time there will be more nullers and less writers.

**UPDATE:** reason why it is important is because you shouldn't talk about multithreading in terms of probabilities at all, because if some scenario is POSSIBLE no matter how improbable it WILL occur at some point.

Multithreading should be discussed in terms of worst case scenarios, like author was at the beginning, though he failed to identify actual worst case scenario for nullers, namely when single nuller thread iterates over all array without being interrupted and sets all values to null.

**UPDATE:** To demonstrate how incorrect 50/50 chances split, consider following simplified example:

Lets say we have two threads and we don't set a priority for them, so they both have java.lang.Thread.NORM_PRIORITY by default. Scheduler will attempt divide processor time more or less equally between them to the best of its abilities.

However one thread iterates over a big array, and it takes lets say a minute to do so.
And another one only sets a single element of the array, and it takes a second.
Also both of them synchronize on one object, so they can not execute simultaneously.

In the begging scheduler gives control to the first thread and it starts iterating over array, and even if scheduler will attempt to interrupt it and give some time to the second thread, second thread could not proceed, since the first thread already acquired lock.

So when minute passes and first thread releases lock, scheduler decides that's enough for him and it have to give a minute or so time for the second thread since they both have equal priority, but because second thread in its critical section takes only one second then it could enter it ~60 times.

Of course example is simplified and there will be jitter and sometimes scheduler will be giving unequal chunks of time, but overall it will be trying to give threads amount of processor time according to their priority.

So reasoning that "in 50% cases it will be writers entering critical section because there's equal amount of writers and nullers" similiar to an old anecdote:

> `- What's the probability that leaving your home you will see an alive dinosaur?`
>   `- 50% either I will see it or not.`

Comment: So I double-checked your answer - again - and again came to the same conclusion: you are wrong. Error 1: Debugging totally screw up thread timing, so any thread-timing-conclusion under debugging is most likely wrong (so does logging). Error 2: synchronized is undefined (my bold text), there is neither a guarantee for what you observed nor can you make a general conclusion out of it. Even my test sometimes start with 20 writes from the same thread in a row. Error 3: you make assumptions on a single test on a single hardware, even your links say that synchronized is implementation dependent.

Comment: I use probability to make it understandable what happens, I say "although no random is involved" right afterwards. The actual chance cannot be calculated, because it is dependent on the implementation of the JVM, OS and hardware, what matters is that with every locked writer, the chance for a nuller increases. By what chance and what are the chances total is irrelevant. Since you concluded out of that, that I encourage writing code based on probabilities I am not sure if you actually understood my explanation correctly.

Comment: It wasn't a single test (i even posted screenshots several times choosing the one that illustrates better). And, since on my hardware there is a problem with resets of several elements in a row, it IS A PROBLEM that will be present on some other hardware. My main point is that you state that nuller updates only one element at a time, while it is not so. Maybe let's go to the chat (Java)? (Stackoverflow is q/a not a discussion site)

Comment: About logging: it may skew timing a bit, but if you are putting it inside synchronization block (as i did on the screenshot) it will show the exact order in which threads enter critical section.

Comment: @TwoThe: "Error 2: synchronized is undefined (my bold text)" - that is exactly my point! You state that every time nuller resets element next thread that will enter "synchronized" will be writer.

Comment: @TwoThe I updated probabilities section in the answer to address your concerns.